# Pushing as two separate arrays and merging into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, while-loop, javascript-objects

I am looping through an array of objects and selecting some specific ones, and then pushing those to a new array. However, when I try to print that new array, it prints multiple array of objects that I have selected!
How should I merge somehow those multiple arrays to a single one and print them out as one single array of objects?

Here is my code:

```
async getRestaurants() {
    if (this.state.city !== '') {
        firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].rest_location == this.state.city) {

                    var newArr = [];
                    newArr.push(data[i]);
                    console.log("Selected city data:", newArr) 
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is what it prints out:

```
 ▶︎ 'Selected city data:', [ { rest_location: 'Gjakove',
                         │ rest_phone: 123456789,
                         │ rest_name: 'Jeta',
                         └ res_id: 'jeta1' } ]

 ▶︎ 'Selected city data:', [ { rest_location: 'Gjakove',
                         │ rest_phone: 12345678,
                         │ rest_name: 'Potoku',
                         └ res_id: 'Potoku1' } ]
```

As you can see, there are two different array printed one by one. Why is that happening and what to do about it?

Comment: define `newArr` output of loop

Comment: @CodeManiac It works! can you please post it as an answer together with an explanation?

Comment: No need to post as an answer, it works because if you place the `newArr` deceleration inside loop, then on each iteration you creating a `newArr` which hold the value you define it in during deceleration, but if you keep it outside then you're pushing the values in the same `newArr` in every iteration